# Sorting rows of the data into different spreadsheets based on row data Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Basically I want to copy a row into the spreadsheet that has the same name as one of the data entries in the row.

```
For m = 1 To TCD.Rows.count
    If Not IsEmpty(TCD.Cells(m, Mix_Design_Colmn_Number).Value) Then
        TCD.Rows(m).Copy _
        Worksheets(CStr(TCD.Cells(m, Mix_Design_Colmn_Number).Value)).Rows((Worksheets(CStr(TCD.Cells(m, Mix_Design_Colmn_Number).Value)).Rows.count) + 1)

    End If
Next m
```

However, the following line give me an object defined or application defined error:

```
TCD.Rows(m).Copy _
        Worksheets(CStr(TCD.Cells(m, Mix_Design_Colmn_Number).Value)).Rows((Worksheets(CStr(TCD.Cells(m, Mix_Design_Colmn_Number).Value)).Rows.count) + 1)
```

If anyone knows of a better way of doing this or can figure out the error that would be great!

Comment: it's just a worksheet name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with `.rows.count`
Look this:
`debug.Print Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count`

Result:
`1048576`

if you add 1 and we got `rows(1048576+1)` vba a little crazy

Try different find the last row. Maybe you will find something there -> http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba